# Converting a C++ library into MATLAB mex

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a big C++ code and I want to integrate this into MATLAB so that I can use it inside my matlab code. If it was a single code making its mex file would have been the best option. But since now it's a code that needs to be compiled and built in order to run, I don't know how can I use the functions in this code. 
Is making mex files for the whole code the only option or is there any other workaround? Also I would like some help on how can I make mex files for the whole code and then build it.

For more insight, this is the code I am trying to integrate in matlab http://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/drf/densecrf_v_2_2.zip . Thank You!

Comment: Mex functions won't help as they don't allow for classes and object based programing.  My suggestion would be to translate to a managed .NET language like C#. You can use the code directly via `NET.addAssembly()`. You willthen have code that works inside and out of MATLAB. See the info at this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html

Comment: @Juderb: that would be a lot of work porting the library from C++ to C#, not to mention you'll lose all kinds of optimizations (the above library using SSE instructions and such)! MATLAB easily allows using external libraries by using MEX-functions

Comment: You are correct @amro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you'll need to compile the library (either static or dynamically linked). Here are the steps I took on my Windows machine (I have Visual Studio 2013 as C++ compiler):

- Generate Visual Studio project files using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) as described in the README file.
- start VS, and compile `densecrf.sln` solution file. This will produce a static library `densecrf.lib`

Next modify the example file `dense_inference.cpp` to make it a MEX-function. We'll replace the `main` function with:

```cpp
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
..
}
```

and instead of receiving arguments in `argc`/`argv`, we'll obtain the parameters from the input `mxArray`. So something like:

```cpp
if (nrhs<3 || nlhs>0)
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:error", "Wrong number of arguments");

if (!mxIsChar(prhs[0]) || !mxIsChar(prhs[1]) || !mxIsChar(prhs[2]))
    mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:error", "Expects string arguments");

char *filename = mxArrayToString(prhs[0]);
unsigned char * im = readPPM(filename, W, H );
mxFree(filename);

//... same for the other input arguments
// The example receives three arguments: input image, annotation image,
// and output image, all specified as image file names.

// also replace all error message and "return" exit points
// by using "mexErrMsgIdAndTxt" to indicate an error
```

Finally, we compile the modified MEX-file (place the compiled LIB in the same `example` folder):

```matlab
>> mex -largeArrayDims dense_inference.cpp util.cpp -I. -I../include densecrf.lib
```

Now we call the MEX-function from inside MATLAB:

```matlab
>> dense_inference im1.ppm anno1.ppm out.ppm
```

The resulting segmented image:

[image: out.ppm]

Comment: I forgot to mention that you'll have to comment a couple of lines in `src/permutohedral.h` if you are working in Windows (apparently the `round` function was being unnecessarily redefined on line 50)

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get back to my machine. Thank you very much. Although I am using a linux machine, but I am hoping most of the steps would be similar. If not, can you give some clear steps please?

Comment: @diggy: yes the steps are similar on Linux: you generate the makefiles using CMake, build them using Make/GCC (you'll get a static library `libdensecrf.a`). This is explained in the README file. You then link against the library when you compile the MEX-function (replace the .LIB with .A)

Comment: I think I have missed something in my question. Running the sample code is fine but what if I want to call the functions inside the src code directly from matlab? Any way to do that?

Comment: Also I tried as you said. I had to make shared libdensecrf.so because static links doesn't work. I moved this .so file and src/util* files to the examples folder. From MATLAB I am running "mex -largeArrayDims dense_inference.cpp util.cpp -I. -I../include libdensecrf.so". This is giving me this error message 
http://snag.gy/8vRjf.jpg. Any help?

Comment: @diggy: obviously you can't cant create C++ objects directly in MATLAB, you will have to write layer of wrapper functions (as MEX-files) for whatever functionality you want to use in MATLAB. A common technique here is implementing a *switchyard pattern*, where the MEX-function receives a command 'string' as an argument that determines what action to perform, like `new`, `delete`, `callSomeMethod`, etc.. The idea is to create C++ objects stored in the global scope and return some sort of serialized pointer to them. The C++ object will persist between calls to the MEX-file.

Comment: ... Check out this example on FEX to learn more about this pattern I described: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38964-example-matlab-class-wrapper-for-a-c++-class (the [discussion thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/278243) mentioned is also useful). As for the linking errors with the shared library, you need to use the syntax: `mex ... -L. -ldensecrf`

Comment: I think making mex wrappers for the desired function would be best for my case. I'll have a look at the pattern too. Sorry for the bother but I am not able to run the sample code itself. Here's the error http://snag.gy/jiW0c.jpg. I am new to making mex files and the linkings.

Comment: @diggy: the linking syntax is basically that of [GCC](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.htm): specify `-lfoo` to link against `libfoo.so`, and use `-L/path/to/libs` to tell it where to look for the shared library (careful the order of things is important). Also from the error message, I see you are using the Eigen library, so you need to add the path to its header files as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61414/discussion-between-diggy-and-amro).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. 'mex -largeArrayDims -I. -I../include dense_inference.cpp util.cpp common.cpp ppm.cpp -L. -ldensecrf' works fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach can be to compile your large C++ code into a [shared library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) (.dll or .so depending on your OS) and then load this library in Matlab using [`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html).
Once the library is loaded you can call each and every one of its API functions using [`calllib`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calllib.html).

---

**Example:** assuming you are working in Linux environment and you have you c++ code in a file `myLib.cpp` with a header file `myLib.h`, then you can use `g++` to create a shared library

```
$ g++ -fPic -c myLib.cpp
$ g++ -shared -o myLib.so myLib.o
```

Now, in Matlab, you can load the library (assuming the .so file and .h files are in your matlab path)

```
>> loadlibrary( 'myLib', 'myLib.h' );
```

Comment: Can I compile my entire library into a single .so file? If yes, how? I have this doubt because I was looking at the shared library documentation and I didn't get how can I do that. Your help is well appreciated.

Comment: @Shai: actually that wont work in the OP's case; the library in question exposes C++ classes, so you wont be able to use `loadlibrary`. You'll have to write a MEX-function to call the class methods.

Comment: As @amro said, you cannot access C++ classes in Matlab using `loadlibrary`. This link describes other limitations and workarounds: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-shared-library-support.html